# Deployed EJB3 in Jboss 4.2.3. How do we access it?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss-4.2.x

I deployed my EJB3 in Jboss 4.2.3. How do I access it now ? I don't see any JNDI names or anything displayed in the console. Below is the stacktrace of EJB deployment.

**How do I write  a client to access the method in ExtractorDAOImpl ?**

`15:38:48,535 INFO  [EARDeployer] Init J2EE application: file:/C:/ejbtest/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/mytestejb.ear
15:38:48,804 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction] creating wrapper delegate for: org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer
15:38:48,811 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction] installing MBean: jboss.j2ee:ear=mytestejb.ear,jar=mytestejb-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=ExtractorDAOImpl,service=EJB3 with dependencies:
15:38:48,848 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.myorg.mytestejb.dao.ExtractorDAOImpl ejbName: ExtractorDAOImpl
15:38:48,889 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction] creating wrapper delegate for: org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer
15:38:48,889 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction] installing MBean: jboss.j2ee:ear=mytestejb.ear,jar=mytestejb-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=Extractor,service=EJB3 with dependencies:
15:38:48,899 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.myorg.mytestejb.Extractor ejbName: Extractor
15:38:48,938 INFO  [EJB3Deployer] Deployed: file:/C:/ejbtest/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp19095mytestejb.ear-contents/mytestejb-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
15:38:48,946 INFO  [EARDeployer] Started J2EE application: file:/C:/ejbtest/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/mytestejb.ear`

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see any JNDI names or anything displayed in the console

At [myServer]:8080/jmx-console/

1) go to "service=JNDIView".

2) invoke the MBean operation: java.lang.String list()

3) it will show you the Global JNDI Namespace tree, where you can see the JNDI entries associated to your ejbs.

You will see something like this:

+- EarName
|   +- myEjbName
|   +- local

For this example the JNDI name used to lookup the local interface is "EarName/myEjbName/local"

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 4.2.x has a JMX management web interface (jmx-console) which can list all the deployed EJBs and their JNDI names.

In any case, the standard name pattern for JBoss versions below JBoss 6 is like

EARNAME/EJB-NAME/{local,remote}

So in your case it might be:

mytestejb/ExtractorDAOImpl/local

I'm not too sure about the EJB name here, you'd have to post some code to show how you created and configured it and what interfaces you gave it.